# Meaning of $a\lor b \to b' \lor c'$

Tags: finite-automata, logic

[image: Question I need help with]

So I have done part **a)** but I have no clue what I am supposed to do for part **b)**, I have been trying for days to wrap my head around and even asked my fellow course mates, none of which seem to know themselves.

The way I understand it they give me automaton of

> a->b->c

But what do they mean about the next state a',b',c' automaton for which is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If the current state is one of $a,b$, then the following state is one of $b,c$.

Comment: is that all the question is asking me to do?

Comment: So it seems. Sometimes the answer is simple.